# Selenium and CAPTCHA - Python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I'm using selenium in my python code and filling out a form on a specific website, however on that website's login screen there is reCAPTCHA. As my code is triggered through a GUI, I would like to use the "headless" option in selenium so I don't need to solve the captcha on the website.

Is it possible to extract the captcha from the website for the end user to resolve in my desktop app?

I don't want to automate the captcha, I just want it to be completed in my app.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use headless chrome just use the `Options()` arguments- `options.add_argument('--headless')`. And if you want the captcha to filled in and verified using automation, then I suppose the Captcha verification is a scam.

Comment: @Willian do you want the automation script to stop and prompt the reCAPTCHA to the user who started the script so she solves it manually for the script to proceed?

Comment: Yes, acejazz. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: Yes you can but you have to be fast, they expire after a few minutes.